# R / Tidyverse: Panel data find surviving IDs over all waves

Tags: r, tidyverse, nested-lists, data-wrangling

Hi I am looking for a tidyverse way of finding IDs (observations) that are
present in every wave.

To elaborate on the data at hand:
We have mutliple waves (>20) that contain IDs and addtional measurements.
For exemplary purposes here is a simulation of our data at hand:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)
wave1 <- tibble(
  id = seq_along(1:100),
  x = runif(100, 0, 100)
)
# In wave2 some observations drop out & some new observations are added
wave2 <- tibble(
  id = seq_along(1:150),
  x = runif(150, 0, 100)
)
# Simulation of Dropout
wave2 %>%
  filter(!id %in% sample(1:150, 23)) -> wave2

# Same with Wave 3
wave3 <- tibble(
  id = c(wave2 %>% pull(id),151:200),
  x = runif(nrow(wave2) + 50, 0, 100)
)
# Simulation of Dropout
wave3 %>%
  filter(!id %in% sample(1:200, 33)) -> wave3
```

I am looking for a handy way to find which IDs from, e.g., Wave1 are present in all other waves (in the example only wave2 and 3). And how many IDs from Wave2 are present in all further waves (in the example only wave3).

#### Solution (with a lot of writing effort)

An easy solution with a lot of writing effort for that many waves would be with `inner_join`

```
### Solution
wave1 %>% 
  inner_join(wave2, by = "id") %>% 
  nrow() # = 83

wave1 %>% 
  inner_join(wave3, by = "id") %>% 
  nrow() # = 68
```

But this seems like unnecessary repetition. Especially if you have more than 20 waves.
The waves allways follow the same naming: "wave" followed by up to 2 digits (e.g. "wave16").
Could it be possible to work with a character vector (e.g., `waves <- c("wave1","wave2","wave3")`) of the names and a combination of a for loop and an `eval` statement? OR with a list of data.frames and lapply?

#### Further ideas to solve it

I thought that a structure like a nested tibble could help with that.
So that I could just iterate over the rows.

Here is a simulation of the nested tibble

```
wave1 %>% write.csv(file = "wave1.csv")
wave2 %>% write.csv(file = "wave2.csv")
wave3 %>% write.csv(file = "wave3.csv")

files <- dir( pattern = "^wave\\d+.csv")
data <- tibble(filename = files) %>%
  mutate(file_content = map(filename, ~ read_delim(file.path(.x)))) %>%
  mutate(df =  str_extract(filename,"wave\\d+")) %>%
  relocate(df, .before = filename)
data
```

**How the nested tibble would look like**
[image]

However I am stuck with `pull` and unnesting of the data.frames, as pull would give me list and `unlist` does mess up the structure. Also I am not so sure about the for-loop to iterate over rows in a tidyverse approach

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  data[i,] %>% 
    pull(file_content)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this in a loop.  Get the values of the objects of interest in a `list` with `mget` (`paste` is used as we need only 'wave2', 'wave3' and not 'wave1' - or else can also do this automatically with `ls(pattern = '^wave\\d+$')`, but it may be less flexible - could also do `ls(pattern = '^wave[2-3]$')`, but this may gets messy with wave10 and so on ..)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mget(paste0('wave', 2:3)) %>% 
   map( ~ wave1 %>% 
             inner_join(.x, by = "id") %>% 
             nrow)
$wave2
[1] 85

$wave3
[1] 69
```

---

For the second case with 'data' (not clear based on the code what kind of operations are being done).  After looping over the sequence of rows of data, extract the 'file_content' `list` element with `[[`

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
    print(data$file_content[[i]])
}
```

---

From a tidyverse approach, we can access the data with either `rowwise`

```
data %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(out = yourfun(file_content))
```

Or with `map`

```
library(purrr)
data %>%
    mutate(out = map(file_content, yourfun))
```

Comment: This was fast . Thanks alot! The nested tibble code was my idea how to solve the "surviving ID Problem" (so it is missing the inner join part) as I was not aware of the mget function. I can work from here. My inteded output would be a table with a row and a column for each wave and an upper triangle of survivors. But I think I will be able to get to there with the mget approach. Thank you